# ComponentDidMount issue in React for rest api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to retrieve data from a rest api. I am trying to log the result but nothing is coming through, My code so far is:

**react**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React', 
      awsApiData: [],
    };
  }

 componentDidMount() {
        console.log('app mounted');
        fetch('https://nc1fi4y2i7.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/api/data')
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({awsApiData: data.home}, () => console.log(data.home)))
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**api schema**

```
{
  "home": [
    {
      "title": "John Doe title",
      "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
      "image": "image/example.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "about": [
    {
      "title": "John is the main part 1",
      "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
      "image": "image/example.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea's?

Comment: API might be failing. Do a .catch as well to fetch promise.

Comment: Also, add the logs from your console if there is any

Comment: Nothing in the console logged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that CORS policies block the resource ? try to debug it by using console.log before manipulating the data

try : https://www.test-cors.org/
result : **FAILED** : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://nc1fi4y2i7.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/api/data. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Comment: No, because I have tested the api, its giving a 200 ok response

Comment: @Sole, are you sure? check this [codesnadbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mcclintock-71ptz) it shows the error in chrome console and its `CORS`, the code in the sandbox works.

Comment: Hmmmmm I have checked on https://reqbin.com/ and I am getting no cors issue.

Comment: I don't know reqbin but they probably use backend technologies to fetch your url. try https://www.test-cors.org/ (your url fail on that site for CORS reasons)

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, I have checked on there and it seems to be an issue. So I will need to fix the CORS first

Answer (score 1):

The AWS API request didn't work for this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-star-2pwry) because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue, the following is working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-star-2pwry), also you render didn't do anything to render the retrieved data from the API call.

but here is a working snippet with a hard-coded data:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      awsApiData: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Did mount");
    // fetch("https://nc1fi4y2i7.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/api/data")
    //   .then(data => data.json())
    //   .then(data => this.setState({ awsApiData: data.home }));
    const awsApiData = {
      home: [
        {
          title: "John Doe title",
          body:
            "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
          image: "image/example.jpg"
        }
      ],
      about: [
        {
          title: "John is the main part 1",
          body:
            "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
          image: "image/example.jpg"
        }
      ]
    };
    this.setState({ awsApiData });
  }

  render() {
    const data = this.state.awsApiData;
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(data).map(e => {
          return <div>{data[e][0].title}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your render methods return just some static markup. 
Currently fetch call is bringing data and storing in state with name awsApiData. 
But even then you have to show that data in render method like.

```
state = {
 data : []
}

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.setState({data: [1,2,3,4,5]})
}
render () {
  return (

   <div>
    {this.state.data.map((ele, index) => <p key={index} > {ele}</p>}

  </div>
  )
}
```

whenever this state got changed by `this.setState` function ,react takes care of rerendering with new data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you see 'app mounted ' in the console?
2. Can you see results in the network tab of your browser that the API actually returns something and is working?
3. If so, try to console log the data only ( remove the setState statement: just to verify)
4. From the react docs, in order to set state we need to provide a call back function to setState() as a first argument

   this.setState(() =>return{awsApiData:data.home}})

Or just..

```
this.setState({awsApiData:data.home})
```

This is not recommended though